# Python: socket.recv() doesn't receive push messages

Tags: python, sockets, imap

Python: socket.recv() doesn't receive push messages

Hello,

I'm coding a socket based IMAP client in Python3 which successfully establishes a connection to the server, succussfully transmits the IDLE command but then fails to receive incoming data from the server.

If you are wondering why I do not use libimap or sth., the answer is easy: I just want to implement an IDLE command-supporting python client which must be written without that library.

An extract:

```
import socket

def runIMAPPeek():
    #socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.settimeout(29 * 60)

    #connection
    s.connect((IMAP_SERVER , 443))

    #login
    data = b"a1 LOGIN " + USER + b" " + PASSWORD + b"\n"
    s.sendall(data)
    reply = read(s)

    #Idle loop
    #As in RFC 3501 connection will be reinitialized every 29 minutes
    while True:
        # Idle command
        print("#Sending IDLE...")
        data = b"a2 IDLE\n"
        s.sendall(data)
        reply = read(s)
        if reply.startswith("+ idling"):
            print(" #idling.")
        else:
            print(" #Unexpected answer: {}".format(reply))
            #sys.exit()

        # waiting for incoming mails ----------------------------------
        try:
            push_msg = read(s)
            # got push message = new message arrived
            getNewEnvelope(s, push_msg)

        except socket.timeout:
            # timeout
            print(" #timeout. Reinitializing IDLE...")
        #TODO: except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit)

        # Quit Idle
        data = b"DONE\n"
        write(s, data)
        reply = read(s)
        if reply.startswith(prefix_str + " OK"):
            print(" #quit idling.")
        else:
            print(" #Unexpected answer: {}".format(reply))
            #sys.exit()


def read(s):
    """Read socket data, print it, convert to string, replace new lines
    and return it.
    """
    print("#Receiving...", end=" ")
    reply = s.recv(4096)
    reply = str(reply)[2:-1] #convert and remove byte indicators
    reply = reply.replace("\\r\\n", "\n")
    print(reply)
    return reply
```

The problem is marked with the "----". Although messages are received in the mailbox, python does not react but remains in the idling/receiving state. In fact, the print line above the s.recv() command isn't even printed.
I tried everything successfully with Telnet, so there is no server problem.

Comment: I'm guessing your problem is in the fact that you're trying a synchronous implementation for an asynchronous protocol. You're probably catching idle messages with the push messages code and get disconnected for not replying.

Comment: Try using `select`, or possibly a library like `twisted`.

Comment: @immortal: I am still connected and e.g. if timeout triggers, the code continues.

Comment: @sweeneyrod Sadly I don't understand how `select` can help me in this case? And `twisted` is too much for this achievement.

Comment: @Qdeep So that it only tries to recieve and send messages when the server is available.

Comment: I tried to put my socket in the readlist: nothing changed. When I put it in the writelist it is immediately ready for writing.

Comment: I found out that the socket only receives data after having sent something. Why?

Comment: I would structure it like this:
`listen for writable socket for 0.01 seconds`
`are any available? If so, write to them`
`listen for readable socket for 0.01 seconds`
`are any available? If so, read from them`
`restart this cycle`.

Comment: In this case there is nothing to write. The server says: ´+ idling´ which means it is ready to send data to the python as soon as e-mails arrive. Python just does not want to receive data unless it sent some before.

Comment: There are several things wrong here to start:
1) You must send all commands with \r\n by protocol.
2) One recv does not equal one line.  It may be a partial line, or no line at all.  You'll have to break it up at \r\ns.
3) The idling reply doesn't have to say "+ idling", it only has to begin with "+", but due to number 2, you may be throwing out additional lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to my comment above, you have never selected INBOX.  You will not receive any push messages, because you haven't told it what folder you want.  Technically, `IDLE` is not valid in the unselected state.

Comment: Seems like my IMAP Server isn't RFC-compliant, it does push messages even if there is no inbox selected.
Nevertheless, the problem was the `\r\n` line ending. Thank you very much, Max!

Answer (score 0):

Constructs like this one:

```
if reply.startswith("+ idling"):
```

are completely non-compliant. The IDLE RFC specifies that the client shall expect a continuation request, not this particular string (which also happens to be a continuation request).